# Ansible says Invalid options for debug: ansible.builtin.debug

Tags: ansible, options

I've been quite busy building a script. At some point I need to generate a password and store it in a file. The password is generated with

```
  - name: Generate new password
    debug:
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: lookup('community.general.random_string', length=32)
      register: password
```

This worked better than expected, on all test runs it actually works. I added some more code to the playbook and now I keep getting

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid options for debug: ansible.builtin.debug"}
```

as an error message and I cannot figure out why this is now an issue.

Using CentOS.

/edited original posted code to include       register: password

Comment: Registering the result of a debug task to later reuse its content is basically non-sense. Just declare the vars you need and use them. Moreover, the `var` option to `debug` is expecting the name of a variable, not a value to display. In this later case you have to use the `msg` option. Last, `lookup(...).` is a jinja2 expression and (except in specific options like `when`...) should be surrounded by jinja2 expansion markers (`{{ ... }}`)

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is:

```
- name: Generate new password
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: lookup('community.general.random_string', length=32)
  register: password
```

Side note: You might want to check if [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) is more suitable.

Comment: Thnx for your reponse. I noticed I forgot a line.
```
      register: blowfish
```
should be there as well.

Comment: Added the line. The solution stays the same.

Comment: Thnx. Ansible doesn't throw an error now, so that is good. But the variable password now gets filled with 

"lookup('community.general.random_string', length=16)": "10caIPtm4)p4F}.+"

instead of just the password.

Comment: That would be a new question.

Comment: The correct syntax is `msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.random_string', length=32) }}"`. But this is stilll functionnaly not right IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This code works and does what I need:

```
  vars:
    password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=16') }}"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ password }}'
```

I can use variable password further on.

Comment: Note that, as is, the password will change each time you call the `password` variable. If you need to generate a password and keep it stable throughout your entire ansible play, have a look at the `set_fact` module.